# Disappearing default constructors

Tags: java, android, dalvik, default-constructor

I've gotten a number of crash reports with the following stack traces (names changed):

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.MyApplication; no empty constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:997)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
    ... 11 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.MyApplication: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.MyApplication; no empty constructor
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
```

`android.app.Application` has an explicit parameterless constructor:

```
public Application() {
  super(null);
}
```

`MyApplication` inherits from `android.app.Application` and has *no explicit constructors* at all. According to my understanding of the Java spec, this means that the following constructor should be *implicitly* inserted by the compiler:

```
public MyApplication() {
  super();
}
```

This must have happened, or I'd never have been able to compile the app in the first place. So what could be causing these crashes?

---

**EDIT:** Here's part of the output from decompiling the ProGuard-ed `MyApplication.class` with `javap`:

```
Compiled from "MyApplication.java"
public class com.example.MyApplication extends android.app.Application {

  public com.example.MyApplication();
    Signature: ()V

  public void onCreate();
    Signature: ()V

  public void onLowMemory();
    Signature: ()V

  public void onTrimMemory(int);
    Signature: (I)V

  // ... some other methods ...

  static {};
    Signature: ()V
}
```

The default constructor is definitely in there, and it's public.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the constructor explicitly? Do you still have the problem when doing so? I'm aware it won't explain why this currently does not work, but I'm just being curious here.

Comment: This seems vaguely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168579/android-instantiationexception-no-empty-constructor

Comment: If you have access to the compiled resources, run `javap` and check if such a constructor exists and is public.

Comment: @Joffrey, I've never seen this crash myself, only in crash reports. I could declare the constructor explicitly but it will be a while before I can see if it's fixed the problem "in the wild."

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I added output from `javap` to the question.

Comment: do you have details regarding the devices/os version on which those crashes occurred?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: this turned out not to be the issue in this case, but if you're reading this question because you've faced the same symptom, it *could* be the issue for you...**

> According to my understanding of the Java spec, this means that the following constructor should be implicitly inserted by the compiler
>
> ```
> public MyApplication() {
>     super();
> }
> ```

That's only the case if it's a *public* class. From [section 8.8.9 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class (§6.6).

So if your class is declared as having any access other than `public`, the constructor won't be public either.

You haven't shown your class declaration, but the first thing you should check is that it's public.

Comment: `MyApplication` is indeed `public`.

Comment: @kpozin: Okay - will leave this answer as something for others in a similar position to check, but will edit to indicate that it wasn't the problem.