# Fatal error using intent inside a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I'm trying to open an activity depending on which item in ListView I chose.

Add click to my **ListView** :

```
private void addClickList() {
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActi.this, SecondActi.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
}
```

This is my **android manifest** for these two activities :

```
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActi"
            android:label="@string/firstActi">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.applicationname.FirstActi" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActi"
            android:label="@string/secondActi" >
        </activity>
```

This is the **output from the logcat** :

```
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073): Process: com.example.applicationname, PID: 27073
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.applicationname/com.example.applicationname.FirstActi}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.arduinodivecompanion.SecondActi; no empty constructor
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.applicationname.SecondActi; no empty constructor
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
05-20 17:28:58.251: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    ... 11 more
```

I think that maybe it's a **problem** with the **intent filter**

Comment: Looks like you have created constructor in your `Activity`, You should not create constructor in the `Activity` classes. Use the Lifecycle callbacks..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939249/android-intentservice-cant-instantiate-class-no-empty-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per android guidelines you should not create constructor in the `Activity` classes since android OS creates object of Activity classes and it use the default empty constructor of the class to create object. You should not be creating object of `Activity` directly.

Looks like you have created constructor in your `Activity`. Remove the constructor from your Activities and use the Lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: Oh yes, that was that, the simple mistakes are sometimes the most difficult to find. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with intent filters.  Read the nested exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.applicationname.SecondActi; no empty constructor`

Create the constructor it's looking for

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that I already tried to add an empty constructor to `SecondActi` like this : `public SecondActi(){ super(); }` but then it only switch to an activity with nothing on it