# How can I call a method in another class

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes:
1. public class UltimateInfoServiceForGear  extends SAAgent 
2. public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService

In the second class, I would like to call a function from the first class:

The function is:
public void **sendmydata**()
under the inner class 
public class HelloAccessoryProviderConnection extends SASocket

So, in my second class I create following funtion:

```
private void senddata(UltimateInfoServiceForGear.HelloAccessoryProviderConnection param) {
    param.sendmydata();
}
```

Then, I call it from my main function with:

```
    try {
        senddata(UltimateInfoServiceForGear.HelloAccessoryProviderConnection.class.newInstance());
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But, here , newInstance does not work.

I get the following error:

```
10-27 22:34:01.563: D/dalvikvm(4973): newInstance failed: no <init>()

10-27 22:34:01.563: W/System.err(4973): java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.gearwatch.ultimateinfoserviceforgear.service.UltimateInfoServiceForGear$HelloAccessoryProviderConnection; no empty constructor

10-27 22:34:01.563: W/System.err(4973):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

10-27 22:34:01.563: W/System.err(4973):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)

10-27 22:34:01.563: W/System.err(4973):     at com.gearwatch.ultimateinfoserviceforgear.service.NotificationService.onNotificationRemoved(NotificationService.java:85)

10-27 22:34:01.563: W/System.err(4973):     at android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService$INotificationListenerWrapper.onNotificationRemoved(NotificationListenerService.java:176)

10-27 22:34:01.563: W/System.err(4973):     at android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub.onTransact(INotificationListener.java:69)

10-27 22:34:01.563: W/System.err(4973):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)

10-27 22:34:01.573: W/System.err(4973):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

10-27 22:34:01.583: D/SAAgent(4973): intent Actionandroid.accessory.service.action.ACCESSORY_SERVICE_CONNECTION_IND : Thread Name UltmateInfoServiceForGear
```

What is wrong with my code ? How can I call the fuction in my other class ?

here is the class :

```
public class HelloAccessoryProviderConnection extends SASocket {
            private int mConnectionId;

            public HelloAccessoryProviderConnection() {
                super(HelloAccessoryProviderConnection.class.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int channelId, String errorString, int error) {

            }           

            @Override
            public void onReceive(int channelId, byte[] data) {
                String receivedStr = new String(data);
                String messagex = new String();
                String weatherforecast="";
                String m="0";
                String w="0";

                if (receivedStr.equals("battery")){
                    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
                    State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                    if (mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        m="1";
                    }
                    if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        w="1";
                    }
                    messagex = "battery|:" + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc);
                } else if (receivedStr.equals("won")){
                    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
                    State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                    if (mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        m="1";
                    }
                    if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        w="1";
                    } else {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                            if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                            {
                                w="1";
                            } else {
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                                    if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                                    {
                                        w="1";
                                    } 
                                    else { w="2";}      
                            }
                    }
                    messagex = "battery|:" + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc);
                } else if (receivedStr.equals("woff")){
                    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
                    State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                    if (mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        m="1";
                    }
                    if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        w="1";
                    }
                    messagex = "battery|:" + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc);
                } else if (receivedStr.equals("don")){
                    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    try {
                         Class conmanClass;
                         conmanClass = Class.forName(conMan.getClass().getName());
                         final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
                         iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
                         final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conMan);
                         final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
                         final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
                         setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
                         setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, true);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
                    State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                    if (mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        m="1";
                    }
                    if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        w="1";
                    }
                    messagex = "battery|:" + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc);
                } else if (receivedStr.equals("doff")){
                    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    try {
                         Class conmanClass;
                         conmanClass = Class.forName(conMan.getClass().getName());
                         final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
                         iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
                         final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conMan);
                         final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
                         final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
                         setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
                         setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, false);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
                    State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                    if (mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        m="1";
                    }
                    if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        w="1";
                    }
                    messagex = "battery|:" + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc);
                } else if (receivedStr.equals("calendar")) {
                    String cevent = readCalendarEvent(getBaseContext());
                    messagex = "calendar|:"+ cevent;
                } else if (receivedStr.equals("location")) {
                    if (loc!=null) {
                        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),Locale.getDefault());               
                        List<Address>  addresses;    
                        try {    
                            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 5);    
                            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)    
                                //System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality()); 
                                cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                if (cityName==null) cityName="";
                                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                                ltime = format.format(loc.getTime());
                                lp = loc.getProvider();
                                    try {weatherforecast=getWeatherT(getWeatherTData(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {             
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    /*
                                    try {weathernow=getWeather(getWeatherData(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {             
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    */
                                messagex =  "location|:" + cityName + "|:" + ltime + "|:" + lp + "|:" + weatherforecast; //+ "|:" + weathernow;
                            } catch (IOException e) {              
                                e.printStackTrace();    
                                messagex =  "location|:" + cityName + "|: ";
                        } 
                    } else { messagex =  "location|:n/a";}
                } else if (receivedStr.equals("batloc")) {
                    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
                    State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                    if (mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        m="1";
                    }
                    if (wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
                    {
                        w="1";
                    }
                    if (loc!=null) {
                        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),Locale.getDefault());               
                        List<Address>  addresses;    
                        try {    
                            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 5);    
                            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)    
                                //System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality()); 
                                cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                if (cityName==null) cityName="";
                                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                                ltime = format.format(loc.getTime());
                                lp = loc.getProvider();
                                    try {weatherforecast=getWeatherT(getWeatherTData(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {             
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    /*
                                    try {weathernow=getWeather(getWeatherData(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {             
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    */
                                messagex =  "batloc|:"  + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + cityName + "|:" + ltime + "|:" + lp + "|:" + weatherforecast + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc); //+ "|:" + weathernow;
                            } catch (IOException e) {              
                                e.printStackTrace();    
                                messagex =  "battery|:"  + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc);
                        } 
                    } else { messagex =  "battery|:"  + w + "|:" + m + "|:" + String.valueOf(level) + "|:" + String.valueOf(nc);}

                } else {
                    messagex = "error|:no input";
                }
                final String message = messagex;
                Log.d(TAG, receivedStr + " " + message);
                final HelloAccessoryProviderConnection uHandler = mConnectionsMap.get(Integer
                        .parseInt(String.valueOf(mConnectionId)));
                if(uHandler == null){
                    return;
                }
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            uHandler.send(HELLOACCESSORY_CHANNEL_ID, message.getBytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onServiceConnectionLost(int errorCode) {

                if (mConnectionsMap != null) {
                    mConnectionsMap.remove(mConnectionId);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Information on constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Why do you need Reflection here at all?

Answer (score 0):

Add a default empty constructor in class `HelloAccessoryProviderConnection`

See the accepted answer for this question. Exactly same problem is happening with you [intentservice no empty constructor, but there is a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155629/intentservice-no-empty-constructor-but-there-is-a-constructor)

Because your class is inside another class you might have to change the modifier. Go through the question for better understanding.

Comment: @AnthonyBonarrigo - Only if you do not define any constructors yourself.

Comment: Yeah... implicit isn't enough to instantiate.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 , I have added the code for class in my post. Any ideas ?

Comment: so, do you think if I change the inner class to "static" then it will allow me to call it ?

Comment: I feel so, but you might have to change your code little bit to manage the changes. Give it a try.

Comment: When  I add static to my inner class, I get a "can not make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService()" error, for following line:  `ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

Comment: how  can I fix that ?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 , any ideas about my recent problem ? thanks.

Comment: No work around. You should not use inner class in this case. Make the inner class an independent one (use new java file for this class) and remove static

Comment: but the  inner class is a function of the class which is currently within. For example, the main class is making the connection and the inner class is sending data through this connection. So if I remove the inner class and put it on a seperate file how shall the relation between inner class and the main class will be supplied ?

Comment: Use interface as a callback

Comment: can you give me a clue on how to do that ?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 , I still couldn't solve this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can call your method...

public static void methodname(Params){
} 

i.e. If it is static method then You can directly call using:
UltimateInfoServiceForGear.sendData(paramValue).
```

You have not created static so you have to create instance of class:
        i.e.

```
UltimateInfoServiceForGear ultimateInfoServiceForGear=new UltimateInfoServiceForGear();     
ultimateInfoServiceForGear.sendData(paramValue);
```